# Efficient bulk SQL database table update based on the datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, datatable, sql-server-2012

I have over 1 million rows that I check for changes and then update.
I completed my program that goes over each record and then updates the database. But this operation takes couple hours to complete with multithreading. I have optimized queries, inserts and checks to minimize the database load. I achieved much better results, but it is very slow.

Is there any way to maintain a DataTable with correct records in memory, and then upload whole data structure as 'virtual table' to SQL server in one update and let SQL server handle the updates?

I have seen similar in the past, it was done via function on Posrgre server (without involving C#). I need my program to be done in of minutes, not couple of hours.

Comment: How are you doing the update? One record at a time or all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either insert your new data in a temp table with Bulk Copy or use a table valued parameter (TVP), then use the SQL [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command to update the rows in the existing table.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the SqlBulkCopy Class?

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx